# How do I distinguish between and restore two different client socket connections from same user on server restart?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, sails.js

Imagine this scenario:

A client opens a browser tab and navigates to page-x. When the client is on this page, I emit some data via socket related to this page. Let's call this socket-context-x.

Then, client opens another browser tab (without closing the first one) and navigates to page-y. He connects with a new socket id. I start emitting different data when the client is on this page. And let's call this socket-context-y.

Now, imagine server is restarted and client's tabs auto-reconnect to the server. Now, I have to remember the contexts for each of these tabs that had socket connections so I can resume emitting relevant data to each page.

How would I distinguish the socket-context that each tab was on?

I cannot use session ids since session id would be the same for both tabs. I cannot use socket ids because after the server restarts and when clients auto-reconnect, new socket ids will be given.

Comment: I guess you can't, not from the server at least. You gotta delegate the task of identification to the client-side. Have the client tell server where it left off and what relevant data to start sending again.

Comment: Thanks @laggingreflex Client would have to send requests every x seconds for that. I want to avoid that. App is more like server is pushing the data. When server restarts, it should continue where it is left off. However, I just saw in the logs that a new socket request is also sending a cookie with id of the previous socket request (I am using salisjs for backend framework). If that is really the case, I can use that. I will see.

Comment: That id of the previous request was id from last tab opened by user and so it is same for both tabs when they reconnect. Thus, it is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by emitting an event on `connect` callback in the server when browser reconnects such as `socket.emit("tellMeYourContext", null)`. Then, clients listening to this event send me the context they are in by doing `socket.emit("resumeContext", contextObj)`. Then, I know what context each client and its tabs are on and can resume the spew accordingly.

Thanks @laggingreflex for inspiration.